# Unable to Call Mongoose Static Method : Error findByCredential is not a Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have defined a PatientSchema, And a findByCredentials Static method onto that Schema as shown below :

```
const Patient = mongoose.model('Patient', PatientSchema )
PatientSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async function(patientId,password) {

    const patient = await Patient.findOne({patientId})

    if(!patient) {
        throw new Error ('No Such Patient Exists')
    }

    if(password !== patient.password) {
        throw new Error ('Incorrect Password !')
    } else {
        return patient
    }

}


module.exports = {Patient}
```

Now when I try to access it from my Login Controller, I get the Error : Patient.findByCredentials is not a function. Here is my Controller Code :

```
const {Patient} = require('../../models/Patient.model')


router.post('/', async (req,res)=>{

    if(req.body.userType === 'Patient') {
        const patient = await Patient.findByCredentials(req.body.id, req.body.password)
        const token = await patient.generateAuthToken()
        res.send({patient, token})
    } 
}) 

module.exports = router
```

I am calling the Method from the Model and not the instance, still i am getting this error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the model after assigning the static method:

```
PatientSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async function(patientId,password) {

    const patient = await Patient.findOne({patientId})

    if(!patient) {
        throw new Error ('No Such Patient Exists')
    }

    if(password !== patient.password) {
        throw new Error ('Incorrect Password !')
    } else {
        return patient
    }

}

const Patient = mongoose.model('Patient', PatientSchema )
module.exports = {Patient}
```

Comment: How would I access the findOne method without the model then ?

Comment: I believe it is not the correct practice to have a static method in the schema which calls a method on the model. You need to use `schema.methods` in this case

Comment: I managed to fix it by declaring the Model after the static method definition. Indeed it seems like, Such a practice of calling the Model method inside a Schema Static method is not very good and leads to really a lot of confusion. Thanks For The Help though :)